# Maya Pose Library - attribute set offset

Tags: python, 3d, maya

So I've been developing a pose library tool for the studio I intern at. I have it pretty much done but when testing I realized a pretty big flaw with the tool. When I set the pose it's positions are based on the local space to it's parent, but the parent is a move scale rotate curve.

When an animator sets the pose and they do a walk cycle, they wont move the MSR. The problem I have is, what if the animator has moved the character away from the MSR and they want to set the pose? Right now it'll snap back to were the MSR is, if the pose was set at the MSR location or it'll snap back to the position it was set based on the position of the MSR.

I need the tool to handle the offset so that when an animator moves the rig away from the MSR it wont snap back to where the pose was originally set but set the pose at the current location in space. I think I can achieve this by messing with the matrix or using the Dag command on the control curves but I really have no idea where to start.

Comment: Are you using DagPose or handling the saving and restoration of the curves by yourself?

Comment: Right now I'm handling the saving and restoration on my own

Answer (score 0):

The tech part is pretty easy. If you're already storing everything locally, it's all root-relative to start with, which is the best way to do it. If you need to do things in world space you can do them using xform(t = (x,y,z) ws = True) to move them around in world space rather than relative.

It sounds like the problem is  a semantic one: you need to find out at some point if the user *wants* the character posed relative to the root bone or not. Probably the right thing to do is to store your poses relatively all the time and just  *ask* the user to specify what to do:

1) keep the relative data below the root, but just don't reset the root.  This would handle, say, an idle pose that is off center from the root on purpose.  It gets applied where the root is at restore time. The root > skeleton relationship is preserved but the root is left where the animator has it at restore time

2) restore both the relative and the root positions for an exact match of the original pose. That would be good for something like a loop transition pose that's supposed to be exact for both the movement of the root and the character pose.

You can also try fudging stuff - like restoring the pose and then tweaking the root position (say, to the ground-plane projection of the pelvis) but at that point you're trying to save the animators from themselves.  1 and 2 cover the two real alternatives: apply this pose to my MSR and everything else, or just to 'everything else'

Comment: theo I'm have a hard time grasping what you mean. I'm still new to how this is all gonna work and I'm still a bit fuzzy on how the hierarchy is supposed to be, how I should query the information, and how I need to adjust it to be offset and apply it.

Comment: It sounded like you are storing the pose using local rotation and translate, yes? So the 'pose' (or 'posture') should always reproduce the relationship of the skeleton -- and controls, I should have asked if you're storing controls and control settings too -- to the MSR.  The only thing you need to do is figure out if the user means to snap the character back to the complete stored pose (thus moving the MSR) or only apply it to the skeleton (thus keeping any changes to the MSR) . That make it clearer?

Comment: Currently I am only storing attribute information for the poses so I believe it's storing things locally based on their parent, idk what you mean by control settings. Talking with the animators here moving the MSR automatically after they've set it is a big no no in there book so i'm trying to make it set without moving the MSR. I did think of just moving the MSR but it was a frowned upon solution. What I'm having issues understanding is you say "only apply it to the skeleton (thus keeping any changes to the MSR)" I'm not sure how to get it to just apply it to the skeleton.

Comment: or well better to say idk how to get the numbers to get the proper relative position. I know how to apply the attribute information. I store the information in an SQL database. I just don't understand how to get the numbers.

Comment: xform -q -ws gives you world space values ( use -t for translation and -r for rotation).  xform -q -os will give you the local values.  You can use the same command to set them in local or world space.  You can also use the 'delete(parenConstraint(mo=False))' trick to snap things together cheaply ;)